# An uncaught Exception was encountered, Call to undefined method

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having this error and been trying to figure whats wrong for like 3 days straight with no luck:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Nsbh::post()
>
> Filename: application\controllers\nsbh.php
>
> Line Number: 25

**nsbh.php**

```
<?php
Class Nsbh extends CI_Controller{

    var $API ="";

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->API="http://localhost/rest_ci/index.php";
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('curl');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }


    function index(){
        $data['datansbh'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/nsbh'));
        $this->load->view('nsbh/list',$data);
    }


    function create(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $data = array(
                    'id'           => $this->post('id'),
                    'name'          => $this->post('name'),
                    'location'    => $this->post('location'),
                    'tgl'    => $this->post('tgl'),
                    'addrs'    => $this->post('addrs'));
            $insert =  $this->curl->simple_post($this->API.'/nsbh', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10)); 
            if($insert)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Insert Succeed');
            }else
            {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Insert Failed');
            }
            redirect('nsbh');
        }else{

            $this->load->view('nsbh/create');
        }
    }


    function edit(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $data = array(
                    'id'           => $this->input->post('id'),
                    'name'          => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'location'    => $this->input->post('location'),
                    'tgl'    => $this->input->post('tgl'),
                    'addrs'    => $this->input->post('addrs'));
            $update =  $this->curl->simple_put($this->API.'/nsbh', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10)); 
            if($update)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Update Succeed');
            }else
            {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Update Failed');
            }
            redirect('nsbh');
        }else{
            $params = array('id'=>  $this->uri->segment(3));
            $data['datansbh'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/nsbh',$params));
            $this->load->view('nsbh/edit',$data);
        }
    }


    function delete($id){
        if(empty($id)){
            redirect('nsbh');
        }else{
            $delete =  $this->curl->simple_delete($this->API.'/nsbh', array('id'=>$id), array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10)); 
            if($delete)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Deleted');
            }else
            {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('hasil','Failed');
            }
            redirect('nsbh');
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what's on line 25

```
'id'=> $this->post('id'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **input** in **'id' => $this->post('id')**

So, the right code is as follow:

```
'id' => $this->input->post('id')
```

You have to use **input** on all other places also.

Answer (score 1):

change from

```
$data = array( 'id' => $this->post('id'),
               'name'  => $this->post('name'),
               'location' => $this->post('location'),
               'tgl' => $this->post('tgl'),
               'addrs' => $this->post('addrs'));
```

to

```
$data = array('id' => $this->input->post('id'),
              'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
              'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
              'tgl' => $this->input->post('tgl'),
              'addrs' => $this->input->post('addrs'));
```

**As you already did in edit function**

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor add  `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

So your constructor looks like this:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->API="http://localhost/rest_ci/index.php";
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```